# Stock Android Wallpaper picker source code

Tags: android

Where is the wallpaper picker source code available inside the android repo. Can anyone provide the path?

Comment: Updated my answer with location to resources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The location (path) for the AOSP Launcher (`Launcher2`) is `packages/apps/Launcher2/` and then `src/com/android/launcher2/`

So full path is: `packages/apps/Launcher2/src/com/android/launcher2/`.

The files are **WallpaperChooser.java** and **WallpaperChooserDialogFragment.java**.

**Edit:**
You need the following resources (from `res`) folder:

`/res/drawable`:

- wallpaper_gallery_background.xml
- wallpaper_gallery_item.xml

`/res/drawable/drawable-hdpi` (and `-mdpi`, `-xhdpi`):

- grid_focused.9.png
- grid_pressed.9.png
- grid_selected.9.png

`/res/drawable/`

- Any wallpapers go into here.

`/res/drawable-sw720dp-nodpi`

- High resolution (720p) wallpapers go into here.

`/res/layout/`

- wallpaper_chooser.xml
- wallpaper_chooser_base.xml
- wallpaper_item.xml

`/res/layout-sw720dp`

- wallpaper_item.xml
- wallpapers.xml **if you want 720p wallpapers**

**dimens.xml**

- `<!-- dimensions for the wallpaper picker wallpaper thumbnail width
  -->`
- `<dimen name="wallpaper_chooser_grid_width">196dp</dimen>`
- `<dimen name="wallpaper_chooser_grid_height">140dp</dimen>`

**styles.xml**

- `<style name="Theme"
  parent="android:Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">`
- `<item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>`
- `<style>`

`/res/values`

- extra_wallpapers.xml
- wallpapers.xml

**styles.xml**

- `<style name="Theme.WallpaperPicker"
  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"/>`

**strings.xml**

- `<!-- Title of dialog that appears after user selects Wallpaper from
  menu -->`
- `<string name="chooser_wallpaper">Choose wallpaper from</string>`
- `<!-- Button label on Wallpaper Gallery screen; user selects this
  button to set a specific wallpaper -->`
- `<string name="wallpaper_instructions">Set wallpaper</string>`

`/res/xml`

- wallpaper_picker_preview.xml

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.launcher2.WallpaperChooser"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WallpaperPicker"
        android:label="@string/pick_wallpaper"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_wallpaper"
        android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true"
        android:process=":wallpaper_chooser">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.wallpaper.preview"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper_picker_preview" />
    </activity>
```